# ReactJS executing a callback once Ajax call is finished

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, npm

I am quite new to React and have the below issue. I have am fetching data from an api with takes a callback function as parameter (&callback=cb)

I am using **fetchJsonp** to make the cross domain fetch request. My problem that I keep getting and error, even though I am passing the callback as parameter.

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: cb is not defined(…)
```

Below is my code

```
 componentDidMount: function() {

 var _this = this;

 this.serverRequest = 

   fetchJsonp(this.props.source)

   .then(function(result) {
     return result.json()
   })
   .then(function(result) {
      _this.setState({
        liveEvents: result.liveEvents
      });

   })
   .catch(function(ex) {
     console.log('parsing failed', ex)
   })
}
```

Please help! Where should I be placing the callback function cb() please?

Answer (score 0):

The callback parameter is being ignored.
exactly here:

```
var callbackFunction = options.jsonpCallbackFunction || generateCallbackFunction();
```

line 54. fetch-jsonp.js
**options.jsonpCallbackFunction** is incorrect name of property it should be **options.jsonpCallback**

I hope it will help.

Comment: Fixed the script in the node_modules folder. The error in the console is still the same. It doesnt seem to like the fact that I am appending

`&callback=cb` at the end of the api url.

HElp!!

Comment: What is the url you are calling? And what is cb? Do you have tab callback defined in correct scope?